# Understanding Type of Java Object from Json String

Tags: java, json, spring, gson

I am creating a simple rest web service using Spring Framework.
I have a method which is assigned to "/check" endpoint. It accepts POST request with body. Body contains the json form of my custom java object.  Here is my check method :

```
@PostMapping("/check")
    public Status check(@RequestBody String body) throws JSONException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {  

        Object data = gson.fromJson(body,Object.class);

        if(data instanceof LocationData)
        {
            return Status.VALID_OBJECT;
        }
        else 
        {
            return Status.INVALID_OBJECT;
        }       
    }
```

(Status is an enumaration which has two states : VALID_OBJECT and INVALID_OBJECT)

I have a class "LocationData". So I am expecting a json format of a LocationData object as a request body. I would like to understand if the request has the right json format. "check" method didn't work correctly with right json format. Then I check the type of "data" in console, it returns LinkedTreeMap.

How do I achieve this goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expect a body of the `LocationData` class in your method:

```
public Status check(@RequestBody LocationData body) throws JSONException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ...
}
```

`LocationData` needs to implement `Serializable` in order for this to work. Checking the validity of this object is then done automatically.

More information [here](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-validation-for-rest-services)

Comment: Thanks :) I can successfuly get request directly into body object but I am also trying to use @Valid annotation to be sure expected json is sent. But it does not work and trying to figure out that now .